# Paypal "add to cart" without leaving page

Tags: php, ajax, paypal

I am trying to integrate a paypal add to cart button on my page. When added per paypal the form included seems to work fine .. but when I use ajax to serialize and submit the form it gives me a 302 error and never populates the Div.

Technically I am trying ot avoid reloading the page, or redirecting/opening a new page when someone clicks the "add to cart" button, and figured i could work around this with Ajax.  Apparently a redirect kills that possiblity as the ajax call can't post or load the redirected page?

Any pointers would be apprecaited.

Here is my code:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".addToCart").click(function(){
        var ev = arguments[0] || window.event,
        origEl = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
        var cartForm = origEl.name;
        var formData = $(cartForm).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr",
            cache: false,
            data: formData,
            success: onSuccess,
            error: onError
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a class="addToCart" cartNumber="#paypal<?PHP echo $counter; ?>">
    <img name="#paypal<?PHP echo $counter; ?>" src="images/butNowButton.jpg" cartNumber="#paypal<?PHP echo $counter; ?>" border="0" style="text-decoration:none;" />
</a>
<form name="paypal<?PHP echo $counter; ?>" id="paypal<?PHP echo $counter; ?>" target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="removed for security">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?PHP echo $itemName; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?PHP echo $Row['id']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?PHP echo $amount; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="0.000">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-hopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
</form>
```

thanks,

Silver Tiger

Comment: Not sure at all why you'd be getting a 302 (which is not technically speaking an error). But as an alternative, have a look at the PayPal Mini Cart at https://minicart.paypal-labs.com/ -- this may suit your needs?

Comment: Believe it or not .. i was able to use that as i found it before you replied.  It works fine :) much thx for the help, though now i have to find a way to add multiple items to cart with php (customer selects multiple items, then i add to cart for them) .... have nto found an answer for that as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `add="1"` method of the Shopping Cart API to submit multiple items. All you need to do is to include the `item_name`, `item_number` and/or `amount` variables for each product you want to submit, like this.

```
<!-- item 1 -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="....">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="....">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="....">
<!-- item 2 -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="....">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_2" value="....">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="....">
<!-- item x -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_x" value="....">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_x" value="....">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_x" value="....">
```

Please check [HTML Variables for PayPal Payments Standard](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HH0D0TA) for more information regarding this API method and the variables you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I have individual buttons for add to cart, and need this process to add multiple items as additionally well.

I did find that you can use a form to submit multiple items using the "upload='1'" method, but when submitted it "overwrites" the current cart items with the newlist ... which won't work as the other items i input with the single "add to cart" button will be lost.

Has anyone had any experience with this? I was hoping that paypal hd an API i could add items with .. but have been unable to find anything like that.